# How do you combine and rename two field names on the same column and display the result?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, permutation

I'm trying to combine the fields "yellow and "blue" and rename it as "green". Then display the number of fans in each Color Category - Green Red White.

Sample from database 'House'

```
|fan_id| Color|
---------------
   1     Yellow
   2     Red
   3     Blue 
   4     White
   5     Blue
   6     Yellow
```

Expected Result:

```
|fan.id| Color|
---------------
   4     Green
   1     Red 
   1     White
```

Here is my code on the problem; however, it seems that it is still keeping tabs on Blue and Yellow column since I see '0' popping out from the result. I'm not sure how to get the output like the expected result.

```
SELECT COUNT(fan.id) AS Total,
  SUM(case when Color = "Yellow" OR Color = "Blue" then 1 else 0 end) as Green,
  SUM(case when Color = "Red" then 1 else 0 end),
  SUM(case when Color = "White" then 1 else 0 end)
FROM House
  GROUP BY Color;
```

Output:

'''

```
|Total|Green|Red|White
------------------------
 2     |   2 |  0|   0 
 1     |   0 |  1|   0  
 2     |   2 |  0|   0 
 1     |   0 |  0|   1
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want simple aggregation:

```
select 
    case when color in ('Yellow', 'Blue') then 'Green' else color end real_color,
    count(*) cnt_fans
from house
group by real_color
```

Comment: he has no green instead he defines blue and yellow as green, so ....

Comment: @nbk: thanks... I had trouble making sense of the sample data until I read your comment!

Comment: I don't believe this will work because 'Green' is not in the database. What I want is for Blue and Yellow to be counted for but have their count combined and displayed as 'Green' along with 'Red' and 'White'.

Comment: @DavidHo: yes. I fixed the query after nbk commented on this.

Comment: Hey GMB, this code resulted in two 'Green' outputs with two totals having 2. Thank you for the help though!

Comment: This is a correct approach, I just needed a comma between the two query fields to make it work in mysql. So in the end it's like this: select case when color in ('Yellow', 'Blue') then 'Green' else color end real_color, count(*) cnt_fans from house group by real_color; EDIT: comma added, so now it works as is!

Answer (score 0):

I would replace the colour yellow and Blue With green and then count

```
SELECT 
  Count(*) Count1
  , Color
  FROM (SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(COLOR,'Yellow','Green'),'Blue','Green') Color 
        From Table1) a1
  GROUP BY Color
  ORDER BY Count1 DESC
```

See [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c39a81/5)

Comment: Wow! That is really cool how you used a sub query to do that. Thank you so much!

Comment: no problem an upvote is always apriciated and you should mark one Answer as valid answer